# start node app from python script

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi2

Is it possible to start a node.js app from within a python script on a raspberry pi?

On the command line I run `sudo node myscript.js`

could I use a library like os?

Comment: I don't know about pi but see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first line of file shall be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

You can call command with [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
from subprocess import call

# Note that you have to specify path to script
call(["node", "path_to_script.js"])
```

Then you have to set `+x` permissions for file to be executable:

```
chmod +x filename.py
```

Know  you are ready to go:

```
./filename.py
```

Note: checkout [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), you can find a lot of use full info there.

Comment: How can I get the output from the command in my python script?

Comment: Figured it out. use `p = subprocess.check_output(["command", "args"])` instead and decode the output with `p.decode("utf-8") `

Answer (score 4):

As Selcuk mentioned in his comment, use the `subprocess` module:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.call('sudo node myscript.js')
```

It's very likely that you'll encounter a `FileNotFoundError` when trying to run your command with `sudo`.  If you do, you can try:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.call('sudo node myscript.js', shell=True)
```

Per the Python documentation, be VERY careful about using the `shell=True` parameter as this could be a problem if you allow any arbitrary user input to be passed to `subprocess.call()`.