# How to Run Javascript code from Python pandas? Convert to csv method

Tags: javascript, python, csv, pandas

I have been working Python pandas DF. I usually Load a csv files, but at the same time I have excel files too. I find out pandas is very slow reading Excel files. I have JavaScript code that will convert from excel to csv. I am looking to way calling this script to automating conversion to csv to speed the pipeline. Basically do conversion behind scene. What is the best way to do this? I can share JS code anytime.

Comment: Do you have a way of running it from the command line?

Comment: @AmiTavory Unfortunately no, I using Anaconda spyder (Python 3.5)

Comment: I assume you've found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8284932/5276797.

Comment: Or better this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10136615/5276797

Comment: @IanS I did found both of them. I am taking another look in PyV8, but still not sure if this will solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: I did not benchmark it, but `xlrd` is supposed to be faster https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd

Comment: @Leb I testing that now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[start node app from python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788729/start-node-app-from-python-script) explains how to use `python` `subprocess` to run a `node.js` script.

`node.js` runs `javascript` code on a `v8` (chrome) engine.  It's is easy to install on both Linux and Windows.  There's an active SO tag, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js

I like `coffeescript` as a way of writing `javascript` code with a syntax that is much more like Python.

I've see Python web stack questions (e.g. `django`) that talk about running `javascript`, though that might be on the client side rather than the serve.

Answer (score 0):

I follow [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) method and it worked perfectly for me. Here is what I added to my code, order to run javascript code from python.

```
Import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["cscript", "yourjsfile.js"])
```